# How to replicate data from development for test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unit-testing

I am running a rails 4 application with a large amount of data in my development db (postgres with postgis). In order to write tests I need the data from the development db.
Unfortunately I can not uses a loader/seed script since the data are coming from an api with quota limit. So it takes quite some time to collect the data, which is not wanted for test.
Therefore I was wondering how would it be possible to replicate data from the development db for testing?

Best,
Phil

Comment: Can't you just clone the db using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`?

Comment: yes that's what I was thinking as well, but I am not sure if there is a more "railish" way to accomplish it.

Comment: I'll explain in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is just a framework - it doesn't have much to do with your actual data:

> Every feature built into Rails  is designed to help facilitate a more
>   flexible & smooth input of data into your system. This means that if
>   you want to transfer a large body of data for a Rails app, it will
>   likely be more efficient to do it at db level

We've migrated many db's before, and it's just a case of downloading an SQL file & then passing into the new db table. This varies for different SQL variants, but if you want to use Postgres, you'll be best [using `pg_dump` & `pgsql` to restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/backup-dump.html):

```
pg_dump dbname > outfile
psql dbname < infile
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating a Bash script and using a database dump over ssh. The dump file is just text with create or replace statements, my example below is using MySql and I had to use sed to convert the escape characters. I am sure you could do something similar with Postgres. As part of my backup I also have to capture user maintained images which I do using rsync. I am loading the database into development but it could also be test.sqlite3 or any other database.

```
# Get database
ssh root@mywebsite.com \
  'mysqldump -t --replace --compact --extended-insert=FALSE -u root -pDBPassword db_name' | \
  sed "s/\\\\'/''/g" | sqlite3 ~/websites/mywebsite/db/development.sqlite3

# Get images
rsync -z root@mywebsite,com:/var/www/mywebsite/public/images/*.jpg \
  ~/websites/mywebsite/public/images/
```